# Group by Time - week with 2 hour time shift

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need grouping data per a week with time shift 2 hour.
Week time interval with beginn to sunday 22:00.

Specifically:

```
2021 CW 1 sunday 22:00 - 2021 CW 2  sunday 22:00,
2021 CW 2 sunday 22:00 - 2021 CW 3 sunday 22:00,
2021 CW 3 sunday 22:00 - 2021 CW 4  sunday 22:00, 
2021 CW 4 sunday 22:00 - 2021 CW 5 sunday 22:00,
2021 CW 5 sunday 22:00 - 2021 CW 6  sunday 22:00, 
2021 CW 6 sunday 22:00 - 2021 CW 7 sunday 22:00
```

etc..

I know how to do for a weeks, but I don't know how to time shift 2 hour.

```
SELECT DATEPART(week, [Time]) -1 AS WeekDay, SUM(Hodnota1) AS total_sales 
FROM [Database].[dbo].[ESP_LOG] 
WHERE Time BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-31 00:00:00' AND ID_op = 1 AND ID_MACH IN(SELECT TOP (1000) ID FROM [Database].[dbo].[MACH] Where ZAOR_Org = 'PRI')  
GROUP BY DATEPART(week, [Time]) -1  
ORDER BY 1
```

Here are DATA:

| ID | ID_STR | Time | ID_op | Hodnota1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14995679 | 78 | 2021-01-03 05:44:01.577 | 1 | 36 |
| 14995680 | 78 | 2021-01-08 21:44:56.697 | 1 | 5 |
| 14995682 | 78 | 2021-01-08 23:45:51.837 | 1 | 20 |
| 14995683 | 77 | 2021-01-10 21:46:08.497 | 1 | 5 |
| 14995684 | 78 | 2021-01-10 22:46:46.913 | 1 | 11 |
| 14995685 | 77 | 2021-01-12 20:47:03.573 | 1 | 8 |
| 14995686 | 78 | 2021-01-19 21:47:41.997 | 1 | 19 |
| 14995687 | 77 | 2021-01-26 20:47:58.657 | 1 | 5 |

Result:

| WeekDay | total_sales |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 36 |
| 2 | 41 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 19 |

I need:

| WeekDay | total_sales |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 36 |
| 2 | **30** |
| 3 | **19** |
| 4 | 19 |

Thank you for a help.

Comment: please show some sample data from table `ESP_LOG` and the expected result

Comment: Its recommended *not* to use ordinal order by - use the column name instead.

Comment: Please share sample data.

Comment: So does the answer below answer your question? `dateadd(hour, -2, time)` sounds right to me.

Comment: Your sample data does not matches with the expected result

Comment: @Squirrel yes there miss a last row for a CW 5. Sorry

Comment: What is your week definition ? First day of the week is `SUN` or `MON` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your week you want starts from `sunday 22:00`, so you should `shift` the time +2 hours and the `DATEFIRST` should be `1`. This affects the `DATEPART(WEEK, ...)`

I am using `CROSS APPLY` to calculate the shifted time and then use it in the query

```
-- First day of the week is Monday
SET DATEFIRST 1

SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, SHIFTED_TIME) -1 AS WeekDay, 
       SUM(Hodnota1) AS total_sales 
FROM   [Database].[dbo].[ESP_LOG] EL
       CROSS APPLY
       (
           SELECT SHIFTED_TIME = DATEADD(HOUR, 2, [Time])
       ) AS S
WHERE  Time BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-31 00:00:00' 
AND    ID_op = 1 
AND    ID_MACH IN
       (
           SELECT TOP (1000) ID 
           FROM   [Database].[dbo].[MACH] 
           Where  ZAOR_Org = 'PRI'
       )  
GROUP BY DATEPART(week, SHIFTED_TIME ) -1  
ORDER BY WeekDay
```

Note : your `WHERE` clause on `Time` might need to adjust as you are missing the 2 hours on the day before

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c6ccb1b0ee7605099c94d60967459c53)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to shift time by two hours then can use `dateadd()`

```
dateadd(hour,2,time) -- will shift the time by two hours. Is it what are you looking for?
```

Two group by every two hours you might use:

```
group by Floor(Hour(time)/2)
```

Comment: I get this:   
SELECT DATEPART(week, dateadd(hour,-2,[Time]))  AS WeekDay, SUM(Hodnota1) AS total_sales FROM [Database].[dbo].[ESP_LOG]
WHERE Time BETWEEN '2020-01-03 22:00:00' AND '2021-12-31 00:00:00' AND ID_op = 1 AND ID_MACH IN(SELECT TOP (1000) ID FROM [Database].[dbo].[MACH] Where ZAOR_Org = 'PRI')
GROUP BY DATEPART(week, dateadd(hour,-2,[Time]))

Comment: I can't execute it. I have this error: Column 'Database.dbo.ESP_LOG.Time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: please edit your question and update it with that query. It is hard to read it in the comment